# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'match'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

The response is an html page, with "Error" within the title element, accompanied by an unordered list of errors.

Below checks to see if the page title is "Error", if so, then grab the first error message in the unordered list, and pass it into the displayAjaxMessage function.

It returns an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'match' on the following line:

```
if (html.match(/<title>Error<\/title>/))
$("#profile-edit-form").validate({
    submitHandler: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#profile-edit-form").attr("action"),
            data: $("#profile-edit-form").serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            type: 'POST',

            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                displayAjaxMessage("Sorry, there was an error logging in, please try again.");
            },
            success: function (html, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (html.match(/<title>Error<\/title>/)) {
                    var error = $(html).find('ul li:first').text();
                    if (error == "The password you submitted was not correct") {
                        var error_msg = "<p>The password is incorrect</p>";
                        displayAjaxMessage("The password you submitted was not correct", "#profile-edit-form-response");
                        $('#error-modal').modal('show');
                        $('.error-modal-message').show().html(error_msg);
                    } else if (error == "You must submit your username and password") {
                        displayAjaxMessage("You must submit your username and password.");
                    }
                } else {
                    $('#profile-updated-modal').modal('show');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image]

HEADER:

```
Request URL:http://misn003.dev/en/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:384
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:exp_perpage=50; PHPSESSID=ssrj2ld6ns51nhkbu3ndj1sre5; exp_last_visit=1386716108; exp_last_activity=1386726413; exp_expiration=1386733613; exp_anon=1; exp_stashid=a%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A40%3A%2292de251be3920633cbb7b9988b1ff912b76d3396%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%22dt%22%3Bi%3A1386726421%3B%7D; exp_tracker=a%3A3%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A12%3A%22profile%2Fedit%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A28%3A%22recipes%2Fview%2Fchicken-tostada%22%3Bi%3A2%3Bs%3A12%3A%22profile%2Fedit%22%3B%7D; exp_sessionid=58ebdf48291051d68fa40842a273d13f4be36f30
Host:misn003.dev
Origin:http://misn003.dev
Referer:http://misn003.dev/en/profile/edit
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
XID:f09c8a4d69001b422f6208a840452c130cf3f789
ACT:75
RET:http://misn003.dev/en/profile/edit
return:
params_id:KPfnEOQIeFiLcGIbulRdhGsGy
site_id:1
first_name:Chuck
last_name:Norris
username:chuck@gmail.com
street_address:123 Main St
city:Walnut Creek
state:Alaska
zip_code:90120
optin-checkbox:on
optin:Y
phone_number:555-555-5555
password:
password:pl
password_confirm:
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:1638
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 11 Dec 2013 02:39:40 GMT
Expires:Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.17 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x
Set-Cookie:exp_sessionid=58ebdf48291051d68fa40842a273d13f4be36f30; expires=Wed, 11-Dec-2013 04:39:40 GMT; path=/
X-EEXID:e7ded3ff5760cd83c30d126f12723a915de3453c
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.17
```

Comment: what is the value of `html` if it is not a string then the `match` method will not be there

Comment: it looks like an xml data... can you confirm the content type of the response

Comment: @ArunPJohny it returns html

Comment: Then pass `dataType: 'html'` to the ajax request and see what is happening

Comment: before that add `console.log(html)` and `console.log(typeof html)` before the if condition

Comment: also can you share the response headers from the headers tab

Comment: everything looks fine so far... what is the result of the console.log()... did you try passing `dataType: 'html'`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I was missing the dataType: "html"

Comment: @Brad I'll add it as an answer... though it doesn't explain the reason for the error

Comment: @Brad did you try the answer from epascarello, you may have to change `html.find("title").text()==="Error"` to `nodes.find("title").text()==="Error"`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I did and it did not work. My problem was, I was missing the dataType: "html"

Comment: @Brad then I post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow jQuery seems to be parsing your response to an object instead of sending the response as a string to your success handler. So try setting the `dataType: "html"` option in the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like HTML is being converted to some object by default.

Why don't you just treat the title tag like you do with the list?

```
        success: function (html, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var nodes = $(html);
            if (html.find("title").text()==="Error") {
                var error = nodes.find('ul li:first').text();
```